# Office Word: Put a different color for every letter using VBA

Tags: vba

I have a doc(docx) file and I want that every letter from every word to have a different color.

Letter a (A) - color red
Letter b (B) - color blue
etc

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I hate VBA in office because for some reason they decided not to update VBA like they did when they updated it for visual studio's macro interface...because of compatibility with older documents....  however, i think this should get you started, because of what I said, it should work on just about any version of word that has vba, i put this code inside a new module called "NewMacro" -- if you use office 2010, the macros are accessible via the "View" ribbon on the far right "Macros" panel (just right of the "Window" panel).. then just type the name ColorizeLetter under macro name and click "Create" button and add this code below (the Sub ColorizeLetter() will be put there for you, i just added it here for completeness or if you have an existing module already and know how to do it w/o the macro window). Also, I assume that only one document is open in word at this time, you will need to add functionality if dealing with more than one document, a specific document, (just modify the "Set X = " line to do that)...

```
Sub ColorizeLetter()
'
' ColorizeLetter Macro
'
'
Dim D As Range
Dim C As Characters
Dim X As Document

Set X = Word.Documents.Item(1)

For I = 1 To X.Words.Count
    Set D = X.Words.Item(I)
    For J = 1 To D.Characters.Count
       S$ = D.Characters.Item(J).Text
       Select Case S$
        Case "A"
            D.Characters.Item(J).Font.ColorIndex = wdRed
        Case "B"
            D.Characters.Item(J).Font.ColorIndex = wdBlue
       End Select


    Next
Next
End Sub
```

Just add in the colors you want for the other chars in the Select Case block and you should be good to go..... hope this helps.

Comment: Two questions: 1. Can I put a two case condition? Meaning: Case "A" or Case "a" D.Characters.Item(J).Font.ColorIndex = wdRed 2. Can I put the color using a number index, to have a greater variations of colors?

Comment: 1. For the first question I needed to put:Case "A", "a". But for the second question, I can't seem to put numbers bigger than sixteen. Any help?

Comment: For the second question I need to use the color Propriety, instead of ColorIndex which is limited to 16 colors. Now using the Color propriety I can user the RGB function. ;) 10x